# Silverlight Webpart: Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features' because of autognerated code

Tags: silverlight, sharepoint, visual-studio-2012

I'm developing multiple Silverlight-Webparts in a single Solution in VisualStudio 2012 for SharePoint 2010.
Sometimes this error occurs in {Project1}:

```
Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': 
Failed to instantiate file "SiteAssets/{Project1Folder}/$SilverlightXapFile$" 
from module "Designer": Source path "Features\{Project1Folder}\{otherProject}.xap" not found.
```

Elements.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/" >
  <Module Name="{Module}" List="113" Url="_catalogs/wp">
    <File Path="{Module}\{Webpart}.webpart" Url="{ProjectWebpart}.webpart" Type="GhostableInLibrary">
      <Property Name="Group" Value="{Company}" />
    </File>
 </Module>
 <Module Name="{Project}">
   <File Path="{Project}\{Project1}.xap" Url="SiteAssets/{Project1Folder}/{Project1}.xap" />
   <File Path="{Project}\{otherProject}.xap" Url="SiteAssets/{Project1Folder}/$SilverlightXapFile$" />
 </Module>
</Elements>
```

Thanks to Subversion: I know Visual Studio added a line to Elements.xml of the {Project1} Webpart.

```
      <File Path="{Project}\{otherProject}.xap" Url="SiteAssets/{Project1Folder}/$SilverlightXapFile$" />
```

When I delete this new line, it will work again.

My question:
How do I prevent VisualStudio from adding "wrong" references in Elements.xml to other Silverlight-Projects in the same solution?

Comment: I'm getting this error, too, but there seems to be nothing wrong with my Elements.xml file. BTW, I worked with a David Schenk in Wisconsin some years back, but I see sie sind in der Schweiz. Die Familie meiner Mutter stammte aus Romanshorn, am Bodensee.